# Element isn't aligned centrally in div in percircle

Tags: jquery, html, css, percircle

I'm using bootstrap to build a website that basically involves "tiles".

I'm using the percircle JQuery plugin (https://github.com/toubou91/percircle)

But I can't seem to get my two progress circle bars to be positioned in the centre of the column. How could I do this? I've tried 'margin: auto' but that doesn't seem to work!

The code is below.

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="percircle-master/js/percircle.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="percircle-master/css/percircle.css">



<style>
.tilebox{
border: 2px solid #ddd;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>
<div class = "row"> <!-- Row for all of the tiles -->
<div class = "col-md-3">
<div class = "tilebox"> <!-- Whole Tile -->
<div class = "row"> <!-- Top Image Row -->
<div class = "col-md-12"> <!-- Image -->
<p style = "text-align: center;"> Image </p> <!-- Image -->
</div>
</div> <!-- End of Row 1 -->

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6" style = "white-space: nowrap; overflow: scroll;">
<h4>  Name  </h4>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
<h4 class = "text-muted">   Price </h4>
</div>
</div> <!-- End Row 2 -->



<div class = "row">
<div class = "col-md-6">
<h5 class = "text-muted" style = "text-align: center;"> Your Share </h5>
</div>
<div class = "col-md-6">
<h5 class = "text-muted" style = "text-align: center;"> Availabile </h5>
</div>
</div>

<div class = "row">
<div class = "col-md-6">
<div id="bluecircle" data-percent="0" class="small"> </div>
</div>

<div class = "col-md-6">
<div id="bluecircle" data-percent="100" class="small"> </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
$("[id$=circle]").percircle();
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you please produce a fiddle?

Comment: I tried to but I'm using a couple local JS and CSS files, how would I add these into the Fiddle as they're not CDNs?

Comment: Just place the CSS in the CSS frame and the JS in the JS frame...

Comment: glancing through the html, I don't see any unusual dependancies. in case percircle is not on CDN, I suggest you look into rawgit - not related to the question, of course, but good to know.

Comment: I'm trying to add the javascript to the JSFiddle but it's to coming through in the result section. But when I have it on a webpage is shows, but not on the fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thanks for using `percircle` :).

If I made clear what is the exact meaning of your phrase:

> positioned in the centre of the column

Then you should also add the `center` class.

For your case, this can be done with 2 ways.

A) Declare an additional `center` class for every existing `div` that corresponds to a circle:

```
<div id="bluecircle" data-percent="0" class="small center"> </div>
<div id="bluecircle" data-percent="100" class="small center"> </div>
```

B) Add a `center` class to all elements that have a "circle" suffix, using [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/):

```js
$("[id$=circle]").addClass("center"); // this gets the job done
$("[id$=circle]").percircle();
```

Result is same, for both cases:

[image: Centered circles]

For further reference, the "skills" section of my [personal website](http://thodorisbais.com) is a good example of a bootstrap implementation together with percircle, that splits an area in three columns and places three centered circles, one for each column:

[image: thodorisbais.com]

You can find the source code for the above implementation [here](https://github.com/toubou91/thodorisbais.com).